# limit child's height to what is left within parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to split the height of the viewport between two divs.  Within the top div, I have a small div and then a larger div that I want to scroll if it does not fit within what's left of the parent div.  Here's the structure of my HTML and CSS (a longer example with more stuff in the divs is in the linked JSFiddle).

```
<body>
  <div class="half-col" style="background: lightgreen;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px;">
      <span>Small amount of stuff</span>
    </div>
    <div class="y-scroll" style="border:solid 1px;">
      <span>Large amount of stuff ...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-col" style="background: blue;">  </div>
</body>
```

I am using the following CSS styles:

```
div.half-col {
  height: 50vh;
}

div.y-scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: inherit;
}
```

`height: inherit` is limiting the second sub-div (the one with the "Large Amount of stuff") to the total height of the lightgreen parent div.  Which (in the jsfiddle) still causes it to scroll since even that is not enough space.  But what I really want is to limit the height of that div to the height of the parent div minus what has already been used up by the divs above it.  (In my actual use case there is more than one div above it, each only requiring a small amount of vertical space that will never overflow the parent.)  **What is the right way to limit the height of a div to the space that is "leftover" in the parent?**

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pj056n0n/3/

(this is my first time using JSFiddle -- sorry if I did it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this only with CSS you need to know the height of the small div. If you do not know the height of the small div you can do it with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  small_div();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  small_div();
});
function small_div() {
  $('.y-scroll').css({
    'height': ($('#first_half_col_id').height() - $('#small_div_id').outerHeight()) + 'px'
  });
}
```

Here you can see the running: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pj056n0n/29/)

Comment: Ouch.  I kind of figured I could do something like this, but I'm really surprised that I have to.  It seems like a natural enough thing to want to do.

Comment: The problem is the height of the small div.  If you set this value you can use the CALC property from CSS. You can read more about this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp). Greetings from Mexico

Comment: Thanks.  Is there no way to say "fill what's left" instead of setting an explicit height?

Comment: This only works when the page is first rendered.  If the window is resized, the outer div whose height is 50% of the viewpane height resizes, but the y-scroll div's height does not get recomputed.  I thought putting the computation into an onresize function as well would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I made a change in the function and it works as you need: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pj056n0n/29/). For the function "resize" work must use the height of the top container.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me.  If you put the bit about the resize method in your answer as well, I'll go ahead and accept it.  (The resize wasn't working for me initially because I was trying to use `$(document).onresize` instead of `$(window).resize` -- I was already using the height of the top container.)